# Login into web page using BeautifulSoup and Mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to log into a web page programatically, using BeautifulSoup and Mechanize.

This is my code:

```
#import urllib2
from mechanize import Browser, _http, urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import cookielib

data_url = "http://data.theice.com/ViewData/EndOfDay/LdnOptions.aspx?p=AER"

def are_we_logged_on(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    elem = soup.find("input", {"id" : "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LoginControl_m_userName" } )
    return elem is None


# Browser
br = Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
#br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

# Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
br.set_handle_refresh(_http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

# User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
response = br.open(data_url)
html = response.get_data()

# do we need to log in?
logged_on = are_we_logged_on(html)


if not logged_on :
    print "DEBUG: Attempting to log in ..."
    # Select the first (index zero) form
    br.select_form(nr=0)

    # User credentials
    br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_userName'] = 'username'
    br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_password'] = 'password'

    # Login
    post_url, post_data, headers =  br.form.click_request_data()
    print post_url
    print post_data
    print headers
    resp = urlopen(post_url, post_data)

    # Check if login succesful
    html2 = resp.read()
    logged_on = are_we_logged_on(html2)

    if not logged_on:
        with open("icedump_fail.html","w") as f:
            f.write(html2)        
        print "DEBUG: Failed to logon. Aborting script ...!"
        exit(-1)


# If we got this far, then we are logged in ...
```

When I run the script, the path of execution always results in the "Failed to logon" message being printed to screen.

Can anyone spot what I may be doing wrong?. I'm fresh out of ideas,and perhaps a fresh pair of eyes is what is needed .

Comment: When I enter your URL into my browser, I'm redirected to this page: http://data.theice.com/MyAccount/Login.aspx. Try changing your url?

Comment: @Moshe: You need to register an account first, in order to be able to login to that page. In the sample snippet, I am using my registered username and password, but although I am registered, I am being redirected to the Login page. I can login manually, using the same uname and pwd used in the script, so that is clearly, not where the problem lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning on the "debug" mode (`br.set_debug_http(True)`) helped me to inspect the underlying request `mechanize` was sending to submit the login form and compare it to the actual request being sent when you log in using the browser.

This revealed that `__EVENTTARGET` parameter was sent as empty while it should not be.

Here is the fixed part of code that helped me to solve the issue:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)

br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_userName'] = 'username'
br.form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_password'] = 'password'
br.form['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$LoginButton'

# Login
response = br.submit()
html2 = response.read()
logged_on = are_we_logged_on(html2)
```

---

As a side note, make sure there are no violations of the Agreement you are "digitally signing" [while registering at "ICE"](http://data.theice.com/MyAccount/Registration.aspx):

> Scraping:
>
> The scraping of this website for the purpose of extracting data automatically from this website is strictly prohibited
>   BY ICE and it should be noted that this process could result in a
>   drain on ICE's system resources. ICE (or its affiliates, agents or
>   contractors) may monitor usage of this website for scraping purposes
>   and may take all necessary actions to ensure that access to this
>   website is removed from entities carrying out or reasonably believed
>   to be carrying out web scraping activities.

Comment: I have two questions:
1. Which tool did you use to observe the request being sent by the browser?
2. The proposal you made goes part way to solving the problem (after a few modification involving readonly variables), but everytime I call `br.open(url).get_data()`, I'm being presented with a login page again, which isn't very practical.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli 1. I've used browser developer tools (Network tab in chrome dev tools to be precise). 2. Well, I'm pretty sure the solution provided in the answer helps to solve at least one problem with logging in. But, yeah, from what you are describing, now we have a different problem to keep us logged in during the session. This is what can be difficult for me to reproduce since I'm not registered at ICE. Thanks.

Comment: It's free to register. Could you please register and see if you can replicate this problem?

As it stands, currently when you login, you are taken to a "landing page" (which is different to the requested url), when you attempt to navigate to the page with the data, you are requested to login again ...

Comment: could you please help with this issue, so I can accept your answer? Thanks

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli here is an example working code that outputs all files from the tree view section of "My Files" page: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/086896f2d67585530be0. Works for me. Sorry for the delay, too much is happening now.

Comment: Turns out the snippet doesn't do what I want it to do, just fetches blank pages. Anyway, I've already accepted your answer and awarded you the bonus. We live and learn...

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli thanks, sorry, what do you mean by "fetches blank pages"? The code I've provided proves that a user is logged in since "My Files" is accessible for logged-in users.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli ok, sure, show the complete code you have and highlight what issues do you currently have. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure it won't surprise you to know that the snippet I pasted is a simplified one. Naturally, the point of the whole exercise is to be able to fetch data from a number of pages on that site, so I can do some local analysis. As it stands - yes, technically, I can "login" - however it's a Pyrrhic victory, in that although I can login, the data which I can see displayed when I enter a given URL in a browser, is not available to me. If you try iterating from a list (say  ["GXO", "BLT", "NGG"]), and dynamically generating the URL, you'll see that there is no data in the retrieved page.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally posted my comment before I had completed it.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli I don't see the point for unaccepting the answer. The issue you are describing in comments and the issue you had presented in the question are completely differen. The latest issue you have is due to asynchronous nature of the pages on the site. What you need to do is open browser developer tools and inspect the XHR requests being sent and simulate them using mechanize. E.g. when I open up http://data.theice.com/ViewData/EndOfDay/LdnOptions.aspx?p=AER url I see POST requests being sent to http://data.theice.com/Services/Query/LdnOptions.asmx/GetProducts.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli anyway, if you have issues getting the date from the pages like http://data.theice.com/ViewData/EndOfDay/LdnOptions.aspx?p=AER, consider creating a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Selenium, as it's fully featured and much more powerful. You can actually see results too:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get('http://data.theice.com/ViewData/EndOfDay/LdnOptions.aspx?p=AER')

user = chrome.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_userName')
pswd = chrome.find_element_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LoginControl$m_password')
form = chrome.find_element_by_name('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_LoginControl_LoginButton')

user.send_keys(your_username_string)
pswd.send_keys(your_password_string)
form.click() # hit the login button
```

Comment: Do you know how to install Selenium? This should work for you.

Comment: It is not actually about power here. Selenium and mechanize are very different tools which means there are different approaches to solve the problem. In case of selenium there is a real browser as a dependency and, even if you switch to a headless, the performance would be much worse than in case of mechanize. Anyway, the question is specifically about mechanize, though I like the alternative you've suggested.